# Button seems to be preselected and fires only after 2 clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

When I click the extension button the *plugin.html* comes in just fine, but the first button seems to be preselected without clicking or hovering it:

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".copy").click(function() {
        $(".status").show().removeClass('hide').text("You successfully copied the answers.");

        getAnswers();

        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".status").fadeOut();
        }, 5000);
    });

    $(".paste").click(function() {
        $(".status").show().removeClass('hide').text("You successfully pasted the answers.");

        getAnswers();

        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".status").fadeOut();
        }, 5000);
    });
});

function getAnswers(){
    console.log('In getAnswers');
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="This extension helps copy and paste questions and answers for the Kinesiology institute.">
    <meta name="author" content="Chris Breuer">

    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <!--Needed in an extension, but not in this snippet
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popup.js"></script>
    -->

    <!-- Cascading Style Sheets -->
    <!-- Need a different source for the Bootstrap CSS in this snippet
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

</head>
 
<body>
  
    <button class="btn btn-default copy" style="margin-left: 15px">Copy Answers</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right paste" style="margin-right: 15px">Paste Answers</button>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I make sure that it does not take two clicks on the button to fire `getAnswers()`?

Comment: $(".copy").blur(); and $(".paste").blur(); ?

Comment: I have moved your code into a snippet and added a bare `getAnswers()` function. Doing so demonstrates that the problem is not duplicated by the code you have provided. Please provide sufficient code, a [mcve], that duplicates the problem. It is possible that part of this issue is in the fact that it is being displayed as a popup in a Chrome extension. If so, we need a *manifest.json* and enough code (including you telling us which versions of the libraries you are using) such that we can duplicate the problem. [There also appears to be some *custom.css* code referenced, but not included].

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the focus, how about adding a manual blur (loss of focus) on that element inside your $(document).ready function?  I'd stick it at the top.

```
$(".copy").blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".copy").blur();
    $(".paste").blur();
 ...
```

on top of your jQuery? That should lose focus.